# How to return the name of a file I sent via POST request from an Azure function in .AspNetCore

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Hi I am new to C# programming and azure functions.I want to send a file via POST request to an azure function and I want it to return the file name. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Demo1
{
    public static class initialTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get","post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                var formdata = await req.ReadFormAsync();
                var file = req.Form.Files["file"];
                return new OkObjectResult(file.FileName + " - " + file.Length.ToString());
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sending the file using postman to this function which I have hosted locally using Visual Studio.But it is showing `System.NullReferenceException` at the return instance of `OkObjectResult`. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jurajsucik/azure-functions-file-upload/blob/master/FileUploadHttpTriggerv2.cs) help?

Comment: You have client code and server code.  The client sends message using a post (body of a http request), the server receives messages as a get, the server processes the messages, the server send a message back to the client using a post (body of a http response), and finally the client receives the message in the body of the response.  Not sure if posted code is at the client or server.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` may be that the file is not obtained. You can check whether the postman request is correct and the file name is correct.

Comment: @jdweng the code I posted is the server code. I am using postman as a client to send the file via a post req.

Comment: Add a break point in the catch.  Find value of ex.StackTrace.